# Wayfinder includeDocs only showing first level reasources

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, wayfinder

I am trying to implement Wayfinder to display on a select few resources.

I have it set up as such:

```
[[Wayfinder? &startId=`0` &level=`3` &includeDocs=`1,9,4,14,17,21,10,11`]]
```

But only the first level resources show in the menu.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How deep into the site are the includeDocs? What happens if you set the level to 0.

Comment: Only 2 deep. If I set the level to 0 nothing changes. I still get the same resources showing (with the others missing).

Comment: I think the third part of Kristian's answer is correct. IncludeDocs will only look at the immediate child, it won't automatically build the correct tree to get to a child further down into the site. I would recommend getResources if you only want to select certain resources, it's much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

First of, should the resources be showing? They're not hidden from menu?
Second, have you customized the TPL's used by wayfinder somehow? Maybe you've forgotten the `[[+wf.wrapper]]` that needs to be placed in each `&rowTpl=` to continue nesting.

Third, `&includeDocs=` only include those specific docs, not their children. The `&level=` parameter only works from the specified `&startId=`. I believe you have to modify your wayfinder snippet to include all the children docIds aswell, (i think they will be placed correctly in the tree).